# Saving video from an RTP stream to a file

Tags: c++, video, rtsp, rtp

I'm trying to get and store the data from an IP camera and I'd appreciate some high level advice as to the best way to do this.

So far I've successfully initiated an RTSP conversation with the camera and have it sending me UDP packets with RTP payloads. But I'm unsure where to go from here.

I'm very happy to do the work, I'd just appreciate some pointers / a high level overview of the steps so I can deconstruct the project!

Comment: That's a very broad question. Are you actually using some framework like ffmpeg already?

Comment: Sorry to be so broad. I guess I don't know enough to ask a more specific question. I'm not using any framework. I just have my camera connected via ethernet and I'm initiating an RTP stream with a simple fudged C/C++ program.

Comment: I'd have to agree with πάντα ῥεῖ; there are too many approaches to answering this.  Are you using a third party API or Library? Are you using your own frame work? Generally speaking, once you have received the data packets from the server side it would then be a matter of parsing the data or interpreting the packets into some type of data structure that is required by their standards or by one of your own design saving them into either a struct or class instance and from there it is a matter of saving or writing which bits are important to a file structure that your application will use.

Comment: @SuddenMoustache with your recent reply to πάντα ῥεῖ original comment, then it would be a matter of taking that stream of data packets and saving each packet into a container such as a vector until the stream finishes. Once you have the packets saved, then it is a matter of looping through your container of packets and parsing the data out of the packets on each iteration of your loop. While you are parsing that data then it is a matter of writing them to a file either it be in binary or text pending on which type your application would use.

Comment: @SuddenMoustache (...continued) No matter which method of writing to a file you use, you will then have to write a series of functions for parsing the data from the file structure that you have created in which your application will use and understand. Now, if you use text, it will be easier for you to read the file, but harder to write the parser. If you use binary, you will not be able to read it without a hex editor, but it is easier to write your parser to read in the data from your own custom file structure.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Extracting the elementary video data might come up a bit more complicated.

Comment: @SuddenMoustache: You will need to get the data sheets (specifications) of the camera to find out the data format, compression algorithm (if any).

Comment: @SuddenMoustache: In order to answer some of your questions, we need to know what you intend to do with the data and the rate of the incoming data.  For example, if the data is coming in fast, you may want to use double-buffering and save the data for later analysis.  If the data is coming in slow, you may have time to perform some image processing (or even display as a movie).  Again, what are your plans for the data?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, that is true, but Cisco should have documents or white papers on their data stream structures. Such as header information that pertain to the buffer sizes, the pixel ratios or resolution, if it is interleaved or not, etc., And there are ways to get this header information from the packets to know how to parse that particular stream. On top of that it isn't just a matter of compression & decompression, but also interpreting which type of audio - video codecs are used as well as if this video stream is encrypted or not and more.

Comment: Another question that could be asked isn't just about what the OP intends to do with the video stream data, but also what information about the streams are important for his uses: Do you just want the information about the video stream to be logged to a file such as, compression type, video codec type, length, aspect ratio, bit rate, etc., stored; or do you want to actually save all of the actual video content to file, or both.

Comment: Thanks to both Francis and Thomas! I put the data sheet for the camera model in the original post (the cisco link). It mentions various compression algorithms. I don't see anything about encryption.
My intention for the video data is to have the camera as a 24/7 CCTV camera that saves its video content (in fairly low resolution) to disk in a way that allows me to play those video files using something like VLC.
It looks like this project will be much larger than I anticipate. I'd really appreciate some pointers as to where to go to learn what I need to learn to do this!

Comment: @SuddenMoustache Well I wasn't able to give you an exact answer but I have provided in the answer a very thorough guideline to follow that addresses your situation, what to look for and about how to achieve it. It should provide you with a well structured approach on achieving your desired task.

Comment: @SuddenMoustache Since you stated that you would like to have the Camera as a 24/7 CCTV for play back, then one possible solution would be to just have your application accept the video stream and just play it back from the stream live. Now, if you decide to save the video to a file for play back later, one thing to consider when writing to the file how long should each segment be: 10 minutes, 1 hour etc.?  The longer the video content saved the larger the file, the shorter the video file saved the more files you will have to read and write. Once you have your file structure...

Comment: @SuddenMoustache (...continued) then a good approach is to have which ever media player of your choice, to be able to play back that content. So here within your application you may have a 3 step process. Parsing the Data packets and storing to temporary structures for your file writer to write a file structure of your design, Then another file parser to read your file structure saving them into a data structure that your media player can accept. Using Data streams with a multi buffer object approach is a good choice to limit memory bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct answer to the OPs question here for his question is a bit broad, and without further information that pertains to what the OP intends to do with that information it is difficult to give a precise answer. What I can do here is to suggest to the OP steps that maybe taken and what problems to consider.

OP had stated:

> So far I've successfully initiated an RTSP conversation with the camera and have it sending me UDP packets with RTP payloads. But I'm unsure where to go from here.

Now that you have an established communication with the camera and are able to receive data packets via video stream it is now a matter of being able to understand what the RTP payloads are, or how to interpret that data. So at this point you will have to do your research on the RTP protocol which appears to me to be a type of a Network Protocol. Once you have written your structure and functions to work successfully with this protocol it is a matter of breaking down the UPD packets into useful bytes of information. Normally in many cases when it comes to processing either graphic, video or audio data either from a file directly or a stream object, they are usually accompanied with some type of header information. Next, it is a matter of understanding this Header information which is normal in a form of a structure that gives information about the type of content this file or stream holds, so that you know how many bytes of information to extract from it.

> I know it's not going to just be a case of saving the RTP payload directly to a file, but what other steps are involved?

The steps involved may vary depending on your needs and what you intend to do with the information: Are you trying to write the properties or the general information about the video content to a file such as: its compression type, its audio - video codec type, its resolution and frame rate information, its byte rate etc.? Or are you trying to write the actual video content itself to a file that your application will use either for play back or for editing purposes? This all depends on your intentions.

> Is the data compressed, in which case I have to decompress it?

At this point once you have successfully been able to interpret the RTP Protocol and parsed the data packets by understanding their header information and saving it to a proper structure, it is then a matter of using that header information to determine what is actually within that stream object. For example and according to the PDF about the properties of the Video Camera that you have supplied the Video Compression can be saved in 2 types, H.264 or MJPEG, this you will have to determine by the information that was provided in the header, from here you would have to branch your code and be able to read and parse each type of compression or, accept the one that you are willing to work with and disregard the other. Next is the Audio Compression if you are concerned about the audio and the types available are AAC(Encoding only), G.711 A-Law, & G.711 U-Law and the same mechanisms apply here. The once are you able to get past the audio and video compression you will then need vital information about the video information itself such as what Resolution and Frame Rate (buffer sizes) were stored from the header information so you know how many bytes to read from the stream and how far to move your pointer through the stream. If you notice the Resolution And Frame Rate there are different acceptable formats available from each type of Compression that is being used:

- H.26

  - 1920 x 180 (2.1MP) @ 30 fps (1080p)
  - 1280 x 720 @ 60 fps (720p)*
  - 720 x 480/576 @ 30/25 fps (D1)
  - 704 x 480/576 @ 30/20 fps (4CIF)
  - 352 x 240/288 @ 30/25 fps (CIF)
- MJPEG

  - 720 x 480/576 @ 30/25 fps (D1)
  - 740 x 480/578 @ 30/25 fps (4CIF)
  - 352 x 240/288 @ 30/25 fps (CIF)

Now this is for the resolution & frame rate but the next thing to consider is
you are working with video stream so the above may not apply here in your case and according to the properties about Video-Stream capabilities from the Video Camera These are the types available that you will have to take into account for:

- Single-stream H.264 up to 1080p (1920 x 1080) @ 30 fps
- Dual-stream H.264 and MJPEG

  - H.264: Primary stream programmable up to 1280 x 720 @ 25/20 fps
  - MJPEG: Secondary stream programmable up to 720 x 576 @ 25/20 fps

With these different types available for your Video Camera to use you have to take all these into consideration. Now this also depends on your intentions of your application and what you intend to do with the information. You can write your program to accept all of these types or you can program it to accept only one type with a specific format of that type. This depends on you.

> Do I have to do any other modifications?

I don't think you would have any modifications to do unless if your intentions within your actual application is to modify the video - audio information itself. If your intentions within your application are to just read the file for simple playback then the answer would be no as long as all the appropriate information was saved properly and your file parser for reading your custom file structure is able to read in your file's contents and is able to parse the data appropriately for general playback.

> Where can I learn about what I'll need to do specific to this camera?

I don't think you need to much more information about the camera itself, for the PDF that you provided in the link within your question has already given you enough information to go on with. What you would need from here is information and documentation about the specific Protocols, Packet Types, Compression & Stream types which a general search of these should suffice.

**UDP**

- Do a Google search for c++ programming UDP Sockets for either Linux or Winsock.

**RTP**

- Do a Google search for c++ programming RTP Packets

**Video Compression**

- Do a Goggle search for both H.26 & MJPEG compression and structure information on stream objects.

**Audio Compression**

- Do a Google search for each of AAC(encoding only), G.711 A-Law, G.711 U-Law if you are interested in the audio as well.

From there once you have the valid specifications for these data structures as a stream object and have required the appropriate header information to determine which type and format this video content is saved as then you should be able to easily parse the Data Packets appropriately. Now as to how you save them or write them to a file all depends on your intentions.

I have provided this as a guideline to follow in order to help lead you in the right direction in a similar manner that a chemist, physicist, scientist, or engineer would approach any typical problem.

The general steps are by following a scientific approach about the current problem. These typically are:

- Assessing the Situation
- Create either a Hypothesis or a Thesis about the Situation.
- Gather the Known Facts
- Determine the Unknowns
- Draft a Model that Shows a Relationship Between the Known and Unknowns.
- Perform both Research and Experimentation
- Record or Log Events and Data
- Analyze the Data
- Draw a Conclusion

Now in the case of writing software application the concept is similar but the approaches may be different or vary as not all of the steps above may be needed and or some additional steps may be required. One such step in the Application Development Cycle that is not found in the Scientific approach would be the process of Debugging an Application. But the general guideline still applies. If you can keep to this type of strategy I am sure that you will be able to have the confidence in gathering what you will need and how to use it from a step by step process to achieve your goals.

Comment: This is a fantastic reply, and I really appreciate the time you took to write it. Thank you very much, Francis.

Comment: @SuddenMoustache I try to help in any way I can; I know from experience as I'm self taught in c++, and my focus of programming is with 3D Graphics Development and 3D Game Engine design. I really didn't have anyone to teach me the language, I had to learn that on my own and when I started learning in the late 90s early 2000s a majority of the internet websites for tutorials were text sights and a majority of the examples would even compile with no explanation or other libraries involved etc. It is as if they assumed you already knew. Over time the internet improved, ...

Comment: @SuddenMoustache (...continued) streaming videos came out and found better tutorials to learn from. The language itself I learned the hard way through trial and error, lots of searching and reading with very minimal helping hands. As for learning different methodologies, best practices, and creating development models that came both with time and improved communities such as this and where I learned OpenGL at http://www.MarekKnows.com I've learned some Direct X but the best site I found for that is http::www.rastertek.com some from youtube video searches.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to get and store the data from a Cisco IPC camera, and I'd appreciate some high level advice as to the best way to do this.

You can probably use [openRTSP](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/) to do this, which can also [output to file](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/#quicktime). For this approach you would have to write *NO* code. Implementing RTP, RTSP and RTCP correctly is complex and a lot of work. Should you have requirements that openRTSP doesn't meet, you can use the [live555](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/) libraries to for RTSP/RTP/RTCP and write some minimal code to do something with the received video. The mailing list is very responsive provided that you ask "good" questions, and make sure you read the FAQ first.

> I know it's not going to just be a case of saving the RTP payload directly to a file, but what other steps are involved?

You don't need to know this if you use openRTSP. If you use the live555 libraries directly, you'll be passed entire video frames that you would then either have to decode and write to file yourself depending on what you want to achieve. If you *DO* need/want to know about RTP and RTP payload formats, read the corresponding RFCs, e.g. [RFC2326](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326), [RFC3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550), [RFC6184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184).

> Is the data compressed, in which case I have to decompress it?

Generally you want to store compressed media in a file, and use media player software to decode it on playback (Otherwise you end up with huge files).

> Where can I learn about what I'll need to do specific to this camera?

If you just want to save the video you ideally don't need to know anything about the camera, other than what standards it implements (which you already do).